# What are the default values of struct members in C?

Tags: c

> Assume all are local automatic variables

Suppose I have the following program :

```
int x;
printf("%d",x);
```

The compiler gives me warning : `x is used uninitialized in this function`. But why don't I get the same for structure members:

```
struct Person
    {
        int age;
        char name[10];
    } man;

printf("Name : %s Age : %d\n", man.name, man.age);
```

Are the local stack members initialized to some defaults? I expect them to be garbage values. If so, why doesn't the compiler throws warning for struct members when used uninitialized?

Comment: Just because you don't get a warning, that does not imply your code does **not** invoke undefined behaviour. If there is such a requirement in the standard please state a reference to the paragraph.

Comment: They actually contain garbage values, and it depends what are you doing with them, as sometimes these "garbage" are set somewhere else and they are not therefore actually "garbage"

Comment: @Gar: No, they are still "garbage". They have an unspecified value as far as the abstraction called C is concerned. Just because you think you wrote data to the same location in memory, doesn't mean you will get predictable and well-defined behaviour from this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583645/variable-default-values)

Comment: @Gar: The term "garbage" is not used in the standard for good reasons. They have an _indeterminate_ value.

Comment: @Olaf indeed, i just used the op terms.

Answer (score 9):

A compiler isn't required to give you a diagnostic for this. Good compilers do. There is nothing different between regular variables and structs, if they are at local scope (automatic storage duration), they will contain garbage values. Using those values could invoke undefined behavior.

The only thing that makes structs different is that if you initialize at least one of the members,  the rest of the members will get set to zero (initialized as if they had static storage duration). But that's not the case when none of the members are initialized.

Comment: @Olaf: Where are the unnamed members of structure objects in this question's code?

Comment: @Olaf See 6.7.9/21. "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: @Olaf Wait... what are you actually talking about? §9 is about "unnamed members" which means _the padding bytes_. That has nothing to do with this question/answer. All it says in §9 is that you can't trust the padding bytes of an object with automatic storage duration to be of any given value. "Except where explicitly stated otherwise" refers to the static initialization of padding bytes to zero in §10. See [CERT-C EXP42-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP42-C.+Do+not+compare+padding+data) for some good advise regarding padding bytes.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I was completely off-track. Sorry, I only use designated initializers and seem to have had a wrong association when reading that paragraph. Shame on me. Sorry again!

Comment: @Olaf Designated initializers follow the same rules as "traditional" initializers, meaning that if you only set one designated initializer explicitly, the rest will reliably get zero-initialized. I would imagine that designated initializers in particular would be very dangerous to use if not for the 6.7.9/21 rule.

Comment: @Lundin: Just in case deleting my comments and that "shame on me" was not enough: **You are right, I was completely and totally on the wrong way** I don't smoke, so no ashes on my head :-) The rest was just trying to realise **why** I was so wrong. That sometimes helps me to avoid falling into the same pit a second (or third ...) time. Thanks for setting me right!

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not initialized to any defaults. You can say compilers as well as standard lack in ability to detect such issues and don't render any warning. May be for the compiler writers it was easy to check on ordinary (basic) datatypes and not for UDT.

Code Analysis tool may give the warnings on such scenarios. CppCheck for example.

Comment: Hmm... I thought so. I raised the question just to confirm since there was no other related discussion over the internet.

Comment: @Insane Coder: Related in what way? Discussion about initialization (or non-initialization) of local variables? Or discussion about compilers issuing (or not issuing) warnings about such situations?

Comment: "discussion over the internet" is a very broad topic ;-)

Comment: @Insane Really? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37636550/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4179345/560648 are just the first couple I found in a few seconds

Comment: Just to add there is no requirement for the compiler to check even for scalars. It's just a helpful extra.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, if you do not initialize the variables, their values are `undefined`. To be precise, `undefined` is not equivalent to `uninitialized`.

For example, on my Macbook MacOS 11.7.3:

```
test@test:/tmp$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _A {
    int vi;
    float vf;
    double vd;
}A;

int main(){
    A a;
    printf("Hello world! vi=%d, vf=%f, vd=%g\n",a.vi,a.vf,a.vd);
    return 0;
}
test@test:/tmp$ gcc -g0 -O3 -Os test.c && ./a.out
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/hetianfang/lib'
Hello world! vi=0, vf=0.000000, vd=0
```

And the same results applies to my Linux machine as well. Apparantly, they are initialized to zero.

`Undefined` means maybe initialized, maybe not, depends on whatever compiler/environment/settings you are using. And there is no way to predict its behavior unless you physically tested it out. The exact behavior might depends on the OS,  the compiler you use, compiler version, the target device (whether it is computer or embedded system or etc.), etc. Compiler optimization settings might also come into play because setting variables to zero takes time and extra instructions, so under strong optimization settings, some compilers might not initialize their values to zero.

One important thing to take note is that "your observation here that the C struct is initialized to zero without explicit initialization" DOES NOT imply you can assume they will be initialized to zero in your projects or elsewhere. You should always explicitly initialize it to zero if you need it to be zero.